# CMakeGUI doesn't show output Log

Tags: windows, cmake-gui

I'm using CMakeGUI 3.3.2 under Windows 8.1 x64. It worked well until a blackout happened (while I was installing PCL libraries) that powered off the computer.  After this,  CmakeGUI doesn't show any more the output section as can be seen in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVyT9.jpg).

I have tried to unistall with "revo unistaller" and reinstall the same version without succeed. I have also tried to install an older version (2.8.4) and it happens exactly the same.

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Using latest cmake in the console works?

Comment: Yes, running cmake in the command line it works.

Comment: Are the colosrs switch to while? Have you tried to mark the fields with the mouse?

Comment: Yes, the colors switch to white and if a select a field it changes to blue. As long as I can see, the GUI works fine except that it doesn't show the log.  

In addition, if there is no error, it can configure and generate the project successfully. The problem comes when the project is invalid, that I don't have information about what's the error cause because I don't have the log info...

Comment: Sounds like a bug for me.

Comment: Have you tried the latest CMake 3.4.1?

Answer (score 3):

If the 2 buttons [Configure] [Generate] are available in the botton left corner of your window, there should be an invisible line between CMake's outer window frame line and the 2 buttons. You should be able to locate the invisible line by moving the mouse arrow all along the bottom lines and at various distance from the outer frame lines. You may even want to test this on a maximized CMake-gui window, just to see if it becomes any easier to locate this dividing line.

You may also want to test upgrading to an even newer version, just to see if there are better GUI handling in the latest version, like 3.5.0-rc1 .

Answer (score 0):

This is the location where to click to show again output log on CMake GUI (here for CMake 3.15.2 on Ubuntu 16.04).

[image: Where to click to show output log on cmake gui]